# PayPal Express checkout - review page doubling total amount

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, paypal

Everything is OK in the Cart and on the PayPal site. However, when returned to the Review page - the Total prices are doubled. I tried looking at `frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/review/details.phtml` but it seems fine - I don't see where it's doubling. Where can I find this? Here is a [screenshot](http://grab.by/K38e).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that `collectTotals` is called within the theme somewhere.  When helping someone else with this issue who was utilizing a third-party theme (Galabigshop), we found that our Grand Total was being tripled.  Sure enough, we found the following code in the theme's sidebar **twice**:

```
if (!(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='onepage') && !(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='cart')) {
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
}
```

Without going into excessive detail, each time `$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();` the total of the order is added again to the total.

The major problem with the code above is that the conditional does not account for the express controller (i.e. `express`), only `onepage` and `cart.` As a result, collect totals is run on the order review page (controller name `express`) and the total is erroneous.

To confirm that this is the issue, try utilizing the default magento theme, clearing your cache, and seeing if it resolves.